# Changing size of rect to fit inside text

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have some text I append to an svg object with D3.js using `append('text')`.

My code looks like this:

```
var countries = svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("id", "countries");

var stateTexts = svg.append('rect')
            .attr('x', xstateText)
            .attr('y', ystateText)
            .attr('width', 'auto')
            .attr('height', 'auto')

var stateText = svg.append('text')  
            .attr('x', xstateText)
            .attr('y', ystateText)  
            .style("font-family", "Arial")
            .style("font-size", "14px")
            .style("font-weight", 'bold');
```

What I'd like is to put that text "inside" a rect which changes size based on the length of the text I append. The rect would have a `stroke` of `1px` so as to give the appearance of a box.

How can I accomplish this? Obviously, width and height can't be set to `auto` (css properties). I need something else there that can work native to D3.

Edit: Confused by the downvote..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this automatically in SVG -- the dimensions of the text have to be computed and the rectangle added accordingly. Fortunately, this is not too difficult. The basic idea is illustrated in this function:

```
function mkBox(g, text) {
  var dim = text.node().getBBox();
  g.insert("rect", "text")
    .attr("x", dim.x)
    .attr("y", dim.y)
    .attr("width", dim.width)
    .attr("height", dim.height);
}
```

Given a container and a `text` element, compute the dimensions of the `text` element (the text must be set for this to work correctly) and add a `rect` to the container with those dimensions. If you want to get a bit fancier, you could add another argument that allows you to specify padding so that the text and the border are not immediately next to each other.

Complete demo [here](https://vida.io/documents/NXRuup4w6jxpZBTBd).