# Using d3 to generate rect that fits text size

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, text, rect

Lars Kotthof has a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224475/changing-size-of-rect-to-fit-inside-text) of how to create SVG  elements that correspond to size of text. However, I'm looking to do this dynamically with data pulled from JSON or CSV.

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/h4uvesh6/1/).

```
    svg.selectAll('rect')
       .data(states.features)
       .enter()
       .append('rect')
          .attrs({
            x: function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[0] - 50; },
            y: function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[1] - 13; },
            'text-anchor': 'middle',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 18,
            'fill': 'rgba(232, 232, 232, 0.8)',
            'opacity': 1,
            'rx': 7,
            'ry': 7
         }); 

    svg.selectAll('text')
       .data(states.features)
       .enter()
       .append('text')
          .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; })
          .attrs({
            x: function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[0]; },
            y: function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[1]; },
            'text-anchor': 'middle',
            'font-size': '7pt',
            'fill': 'rgb(25,25,25)',
            'opacity': 1
         });
```

The concept I'm not grasping is how I can write a function, similar to Lars's, that creates both the `<rect>` and the `<text>` and uses the dimensions of the text to determine the dimensions of the rectangle.

Comment: Why bother with that? Why not do it this way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013492/1038015 no measuring required.

Comment: It's a good idea, but the `filter` attribute seems to cause issues with anti-aliasing.

Comment: I think there's another answer you can try on that same question if you get antialiasing issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution and associated [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/nuffp3ko/1/).  Basically what I did is assigned corresponding IDs to each rect and text, and then after the texts were generated, went adjusted the rect size based on the text.  Additionally, the x position of the text had to be adjusted accordingly as well.

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
   .data(states.features)
   .enter()
   .append('rect')
      .attrs({
        y: function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[1] - 13; },
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        'width': 100,
        'height': 18,
        'fill': 'rgba(232, 232, 232, 0.8)',
        'opacity': 1,
        'rx': 7,
        'ry': 7
     }); 

svg.selectAll('text')
   .data(states.features)
   .enter()
   .append('text')
      .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; })
      .attrs({
        x: function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[0]; },
        y: function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[1]; },
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        'font-size': '7pt',
        'fill': 'rgb(25,25,25)',
        'opacity': 1,
        id: function(d) { return 'text' + d.id }
     });   

svg.selectAll('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return document.getElementById('text'+d.id).getBBox().width; })
    .attr('x', function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[0] - document.getElementById('text'+d.id).getBBox().width / 2; });
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good solution to my question, as with the `filter` solution I did get the antialiasing issues. I'm curious what kind of impact this has on load time, but the method will be helpful for me in approaching new problems.